# How to create (vertically) faceted plots in ggplot2 with dynamic heights such that all facets have the same scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When creating faceted plots, all the facets have the same dimensions. Any way to make plots with differing dimensions? In particular, any way to make sure vertically stacked facets all have the same y-scale?

I'm trying the following:

```
qplot(score, ..count.., data=df, geom='density', position='stack') +
  facet_grid(method~., scales='free', space='free')
```

but I get:

```
Error in if (length(range) == 1 || diff(range) == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Hard to know what the problem is without a reproducible example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This incantation ended up working for me:

```
qplot(score, ..count.., data=df, geom='density', fill=I('black')) +
opts(strip.text.y = theme_text()) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,999,by=50)) +
facet_grid(method~., scale='free', space='free'))
```